# I need to create a SQL table using dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, ssms

I am trying to write a stored procedure in **SSMS** that creates a table, along with two columns with the subject of the table as the single parameter. The table must be named `t` followed by the subject of the table. As for the columns, the first column is an **auto-incrementing** surrogate key ID field (and the *primary key*) that is named as the subject of the table, followed by `ID`.

The second column is a natural key which is named as the subject of the table. For instance, a table to be created with the subject being Student would create a table named `tStudent`, with a `StudentID` surrogate key column as well as a natural key column named Student. I am trying to do this using a **dynamic SQL statement** (which I am new to) and keep running into issues while trying to implement my natural key column.

```
ALTER PROC spCreateTable 
    @subjectOfTable varchar(50)
AS
DECLARE @dynamicSQL nvarchar(500),
        @tableName varchar(50),
        @tableID varchar(50);

SET @tableName = ('t' + @subjectOfTable);
SET @tableID = (@subjectOfTable + 'ID');
SET @dynamicSQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @tableName + ' ( '+ @tableID + ' INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) ' + @subjectOfTable + ' VARCHAR(50) ) ';

EXEC (@dynamicSQL)
GO
```

I can get it to work correctly while just adding the `tableID` column, but keep having syntax issues with the natural key column `subjectOfTable`. Someone please help!

Comment: you missed a comma i think right before second column

Comment: Thanks. I have been editing it so much, trying new things that I forgot to put that back in. I've been staring at the screen a little too long.

Comment: You should probably rethink the entire thing. Creating tables is something that belongs in design time, not run time. If you have a procedure that creates table, it's usually a sign you are doing something wrong.